# What is the &#xA; character?

Tags: html, xml

What's the meaning of this char?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but according to the website in the above comment, &#xa; is invalid, which is entirely incorrect.

Comment: @akousmata: are you saying that the linked website is not correct?

Comment: Yes, from the website:  `&#10; | &#xa; | %a = invalid` as you can see from the correct answer, the HTML encoding for &#xa; is a Line Feed, not invalid as the site claims, unless I'm misunderstanding something about the sites information.

Comment: The `&#` notation is a XML encoding for special characters. See also this article [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

That would be an HTML Encoded Line Feed character (using the hexadecimal value).

The decimal value would be `&#10;`

Answer (score 30):

It is the equivalent to \n -> LF (Line Feed).

Sometimes it is used in HTML and JavaScript. Otherwise in .NET environments, use `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 12):

It's the ASCII/UTF code for `LF` (`0A`) - Unix-based systems are using it as the newline character, while Windows uses the CR-LF PAIR (`OD0A`).

Answer (score 4):

It's a linefeed character. How you use it would be up to you.

Answer (score 3):

`&#xA;` is the HTML representation in hex of a `line feed` character. It represents a new line on Unix and Unix-like (for example) operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ASCII format.

Please consider that:

> Some data (like URLs) can be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>   Since data often contain characters outside the ASCII set, so it has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

To find it yourself, you can visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII, there you can find big tables of characters. The one you are looking is in `Control Characters` table.

Digging to table you can find

`Oct    Dec    Hex    Name
 012   10      0A     Line Feed`

In the html file you can use Dec and Hex representation of charters

The `Dec` is represented with `&#10;`

The `Hex` is represented with `&#x0A` (or you can omit the leading zero `&#xA`)

There is a good converter at https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ .

Answer (score 2):

## HTML hex character entity for U+000A Line Feed

This is a representation of [`Unicode Character 'LINE FEED (LF)' (U+000A)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)

`&#xa;` is the [HTML character entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)'s way of saying: *give me the Unicode character at hexadecimal codepoint 0xA*

And because hex 0xA is the same as decimal 10, here's another way of getting the same character: `&#10;`

---

Related:

```
$ echo -n '&#xa;' | recode html..ascii | xxd
00000000: 0a                                       .
✓

$ ascii 0a
ASCII 0/10 is decimal 010, hex 0a, octal 012, bits 00001010: called ^J, LF, NL
Official name: Line Feed
Other names: Newline, \n
```

Further reading: [Bash script to convert from HTML entities to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929492/bash-script-to-convert-from-html-entities-to-characters)

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ascii Key Code for Line Feed (Lf).

You can find a list of the descriptions, together with the decimal and Hex values here [enter link description here](https://www.codetable.net/asciikeycodes)